# Objectivc C preserve context of layer

Tags: objective-c, cgcontext

I am drawing a shape to a `CALayer` using `-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` like so:

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
... draw path
CGContextClosePath(ctx);

CGContextClip(ctx);
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
[self.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);  // Paint the context
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

I have multiple UIViews with this CALayer attached to them. When a particular event happens then I need to take the CALayer context drawing and apply it to the other CALayer in the other UIView while preserving the current context drawing. I tried caching the `UImage` from the context and then re-applying it but to no avail.

```
self.cachedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

I tried this to re-apply it:

```
self.contents = (id)self.cachedImage.CGImage;
```

or

```
[self.cachedImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
```

I am very new at this and need some direction on how I can preserve or add to the context drawing of these CALayers

**EDIT**

I also attempted this on a `UIView` rather than a `CALayer`. This is what I have:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.cachedImage.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    ... draw path ...
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);
    CGContextClip(ctx);
    [self.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    self.cachedImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.cachedImage setAlpha:1.0];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

This still clears out the past context drawing. If I NSLog `self.cachedImage.image` it is definitely there.

Part of me wonders if it has anything to do with this: `CGContextClip()`

Comment: Did you try the `UIView` approach with `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` set to `NO`?

Comment: Yes. But did change anything. Context still gets cleared

Comment: Okay, I'm probably being thick, but can you elaborate on exactly what you want to do here? You're explicitly not meant to mutate the state of your layer or view in `drawRect:` or `drawInContext:`, merely present your current state. So if you want it as a context that would logically imply a bitmap context that you merely push onwards. But you seem to want to render paths?

Comment: I am wanting to take the Context drawing of two different but similar UIViews and merge them. It's for a puzzle application. I am so new to this that I am not sure if I even doing this the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not be setting anything in `-drawRect:`, only drawing. What you're attempting to do should likely be done elsewhere. From what I understand you are trying to "merge" the drawing of two views into one image? If so, create image contexts, draw, and save those images seperately, outside of your `-drawRect:` Like [Tommy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427332/tommy) states, you should only be drawing the state of your view, not changing anything about the object.

Take a look at [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext) for a good place to start (p.s. this can be run on a background thread too!).